# Como criar uma pasta com nome da data atual

Tags: java, arquivo, data

Eu estou tentando criar uma pasta com o nome igual a data atual mas simplesmente não cria.

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;


public class PastaData {

Date data = new Date();
SimpleDateFormat formatar = new SimpleDateFormat("d/m/y");
String dataFormatada = new formatar.format(data);
System.out.println("dataFormatada");

File file = new File(dataFormatada);
file.mkdir();



}
```

Comment: Qual o path da criação da pasta? Do jeito que está no código, está criando dentro do seu projeto. Tente assim: `File file = new File("C:\" + dataFormatada);` e vá nesse endereço e veja se criou.

Comment: @diegofm provavelmente diretamente no C: ele não terá permissão de acesso. Acho que é melhor criar na pasta do projeto, mas não dentro do projeto.

Comment: @Sorack como você sabe que ele não tem acesso?

Comment: Hehehehehe geralmente no meu PC da isso, e meu usuário é administrador

Comment: Eu tentei usar o comando que você me disse mas mesmo assim não mudou nada :(

Comment: @Sorack depende de como seu sistema está com as diretivas de segurança configuradas, ou se o seu usuário não for administrador, aqui funciona normalmente sem precisar elevar privilégios do prompt, mas meu usuário é administrador do sistema.

Comment: Alguma das resposta lhe foi útil? Não esqueça de escolher uma e marcar o ✅ para que possa ser utilizada caso alguém tenha uma dúvida similar!

Answer (score 4):

O problema é que o windows não permite [criação de arquivos ou pastas com `/`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10708449/5524514), é um caractere inválido.

Altere a máscara de formatação da data para `"d-m-y"` e funcionará normalmente.
E não esqueça de importar a classe `SimpleDateFormat`.

o exemplo abaixo:

```
import java.util.*;
import java.io.File;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class PastaData {

   public static void main(String[] args) {

      Date data = new Date();
      SimpleDateFormat formatar = new SimpleDateFormat("d-m-y");
      String dataFormatada = formatar.format(data);  

      try{      

         File f = new File(dataFormatada);

         System.out.println(dataFormatada);

         f.mkdir();

      }catch(Exception e){

         e.printStackTrace();
      }
   }
}
```

Referência oficial: [Naming Files, Paths, and Namespaces](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365247(v=vs.85).aspx)

Comment: Irei tentar assim muito obrigado!

Comment: @FelipeMorenoBorges caso lhe atenda, não se esqueça de clicar no ✅ para indicar que esta solução lhe atendeu. Caso dê algum problema, só falar aqui :)

Answer (score 2):

Pode utilizar [`LocalDate#now().toString()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/LocalDate.html#toString--) que retorna a data atual em formato *yyyy-mm-dd*:

```
final String directory = LocalDate.now().toString();
Files.createDirectory(Paths.get("C:", directory)); // cria um diretório na unidade C:
```